# Confirmation Draw has completed

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have created a custom button that will allow users to select with columns to output to CSV so the button is not created as part of the table initialization.  I have a modal that pops up with checkboxes created off the column headers for selection. It is worth noting I have regex search on each column header.  The issue is I am using server side processing and as a result the only exported rows are those visible. As a work around I have set it up to get the page.info().recordsDisplay and set the length of the page to that and draw.  The modal pops up and says it is loading data from server once table is fully populated the HTML of the modal will change to the checkboxes for export. Once exported the table is reverted back to the default length. What I need to do is capture when the rows are fully rendered so I can do the HTML switch.  Right now I am setting a timeout.  The data can take a while to populate as there are some 13k rows if now search is applied.  What is the best way to do this and is there a more efficient way?

```
    var tableHeaders = [];
    var table = $('#example').DataTable().columns().every( function () {
        tableHeaders.push( $(this.header()).text() );
    });
    var pageLength = table.page.info().length;
    table.context['0']._iDisplayLength = table.page.info().recordsDisplay;
    table.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue with server-side processing parameters [`start/length`](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Configuration) that define the portion of data being requested from the server upon each draw.

If your source data has huge number of rows, chances are they're not sent all at once to make use of server-side processing. So, you can try to manipulate those parameters.

Alternatively, you may try to make use of [`draw`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) event fired upon each redraw.

Comment: The filtering is not the concern, it is the fact I have to load all the rows in the table in order to get all the data to export because of server side processing. Might just need to look into some sort of direct DB connection. Will be faster than trying to load data into the table.  Is there not a function to export ALL data through the API with search applied?

Comment: Edited my answer, missed the key point regarding server-side processing.